# Console shows "List`1[System.String]" when trying to read particular JSON field

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

When I called a Restful Web API, I received a JSON string as the response from the server. So, I deserialized the JSON string to a .NET object with the following codes:

`RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);`

The response (JSON string) of my API call is below:

```
{"Observation":{"FeelsLike":{"Text":["23"]},"WindDirection":{"Value":"SE","Text":["SE"],"ImageKey":"windSE"},"WindSpeed":{"Text":["14km/h"]},"Pressure":{"Text":["102.4kPa"]},"Visibility":{"Text":["16.0km"]},"Ceiling":{"Text":["21900ft"]},"Humidity":{"Text":["70%"]},"Sunrise":{"Text":["06:38"]},"Sunset":{"Text":["19:57"]},"ExpirationTime":{"Value":8286},"RefreshTime":{"Value":1267},"Timestamp":{"GMT":"2014-08-29T15:45","Local":"2014-08-29T11:45","Text":["August 29 2014, 11:45 AM"]},"Icon":{"Value":"OVC","TextKey":"obs24","ImageKey":"wxicon8"},"Temperature":{"Text":["19","°C"]}}}
```

Now, I want to access (store 23 to a variable) the value 23 in "FeelsLike":{"Text":["23"]}, how do I do that?

I tried the following approach, but weren't successful:

Step 1). I converted JSON string to C# classes (link to classes code: http://goo.gl/OTKL4l) on http://json2csharp.com/, and I tried accessing the value 23 with this line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Observation.FeelsLike.Text);
```

But I got the following output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Comment: you are writing the text property as a Array ["23"], you should use obj.Observation.FeelsLike.Text[0]

Comment: Whenever seeing a strange `ToString` (called implicitly by WriteLine), find out *what* object it represents. [*Using the debugger*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx) is an invaluable tool and is often much more practical than WriteLine because it allows live inspection (and modification) of variables/expressions.

Comment: Anyway, what *should* happen when the JSON is `{"Text":[]}` or `{"Text":["Foo", "Bar"]}`? Make sure to explicitly state the desired behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your JSON object, the key for FeelsLike, actually returns a list. So by extension

```
FeelsLike.Text
```

actually prints a list.
If you want the first object in the list, try

```
FeelsLike.Text.get(0); or FeelsLike.Text[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`Text` is an array, so it is being deserialized as a `List<string>` (which is quite clear from the string value you posted at the end of your question). Do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Observation.FeelsLike.Text.FirstOrDefault() ?? "");
```

Answer (score 0):

using JSON.NET library [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) you can do something like this:

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

and then access `"FeelsLike":{"Text":["23"]}` with `obj.FeelsLike.Text;`

Comment: `obj.FeelsLike.Text` is *still* a List, even with `dynamic`/non-POCO usage. The solution is to access the contents of the List somehow (depending on need).